# c++ i/o prob when appending file

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to write an object to a file. When I run it once, it works perfectly -- as the file is empty --, but when I try to run it a second time, the program crashes after taking nothing from the inputs.

Any ideas on what is wrong in this code?

```
class student
{
    fstream file;
    int roll,mks;
public:
    void openFile();
    void getInput();
    void disp();
};

void student::openFile()
{
    file.open("student.dat",ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);
    if(!file)
    {
        cout<<"write error";
        _sleep(2000);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void student::getInput()
{
    openFile();
    cout<<"\nenter roll no.:";
    cin>>roll;
    cout<<"\nenter marks:";
    cin>>mks;
    file.write((char *)this,sizeof(this));
    file.seekg(0);
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        file.read((char *)this,sizeof(this));
        if(file.eof())
        {
            break;
        }
        disp();
    }
    file.close();
}

void student::disp()
{
    cout<<"\n\n\troll no.:"<<roll;
    cout<<"\n\tmarks:"<<mks;
}

int main()
{
    student a;
    a.getInput();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joachim pointed out, your `void student::getInput()` destroys the `file`, as you're using `this` to read back the contents.

A user defined structure will probably suit for your need.

Something like this (this, this, not that `this` :D) :

```
class student
{
    //....
    data_struct data; //typedef struct { int roll,mks;} data_struct;
  //...
};
```

And then

```
void student::getInput()
{
    openFile();
    cout<<"\nenter roll no.:";
    cin>>data.roll;
    cout<<"\nenter marks:";
    cin>>data.mks;
    file.write((char *)&data,sizeof(data_struct));
    file.seekg(0);
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        file.read((char *)&data,sizeof(data_struct));
        disp();
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read into `this` you *overwrite* the current file stream! That will cause the next file operation with the file stream to behave undefined.

Using `this` when reading and/or writing files is almost never a good idea, especially if you have pointers and/or non-POD type variables (like for example an `std::fstream`). Instead I suggest you put the data you need to read/write in a separate structure, and use that instead.